# Aligning divs perfectly like a table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the following, but I cant even though I am trying to use divs and flex. I have tried everything possible but cant figure out what to do.

[image]

code:

```
            <Box
                sx={{
                    '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
                    margin: '0 auto',
                    maxWidth: '500px',
                    padding: '0px',
                    width: '100%',
                    marginTop: '20px',
                    marginBottom: '20px',
                    borderRadius: '5px',
                    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
                    boxShadow: '0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',

                }}
                noValidate
                autoComplete="off">
                <div className='attendance-header'>
                    <span className='attendance-header-left'>
                        Names
                    </span>

                    <span className='attendance-header-right ml-5'>
                        Status
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className='attendance-container'>
                    {names.map((name, index) => {
                        return (
                            <span className='attendance-row'>
                                <span className='attendance-name'>
                                    {name}
                                </span>
                                <span className=''>
                                    <FormControl component="fieldset">
                                        {/* <FormLabel component="legend">Status</FormLabel> */}
                                        <RadioGroup aria-label="status" name="status" value="present" row>
                                            <FormControlLabel value="present" control={<Radio />} label="Present" />
                                            <FormControlLabel value="absent" control={<Radio />} label="Absent" />
                                        </RadioGroup>
                                    </FormControl>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        )
                    }
                    )}
                </div>
            </Box>
```

CSS:

```
.attendance-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.attendance-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.attendance-name{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I have attached the react code and the css. I have tried using grid but of no avail. So I am really confused right now.

Comment: Have you tried `align-items:baseline;` inside the flex container ? I believe in your case it's the row that contains the elements you want to align.

Comment: Just use tables.